# Не передаются данные через POST

Tags: post, php

```
<input type="hidden" class="deleteID" name="deleteID" value="d">
<input type="submit" />

print_r($_POST);
```

не выводится ничего.

Comment: А где теги `form`?

Comment: здесь не добавил а странице есть

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" class="deleteID" name="deleteID">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: А что там должно выводиться? И когда?

Comment: А в скрипте больше ничего нет, это все? В других браузерах пробовали? Сервер ваш или хостера? Может быть, что-то с конфигурацией PHP.

Comment: @FunnY77, заполните атрибут `action` у формы.

Comment: А непосредственно $_POST['deleteID'] существует? var_dump($_POST); что-то выведет?

Comment: А print_r($_POST) обернут в `<?php ?>`?